# How to encrypt the data columns in SQL using Azure Key Vault?

Tags: sql-server, azure, encryption, azure-keyvault

My requirement is:

1. Data from Azure Blob will load into Azure SQL server with 10 columns.
2. I need to encrypt the data for 3-4 columns in Azure SQL server.
3. Is it possible with **Azure Key Vault**?

Is this possible or is there any other secure way to do encryption in Azure SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's called Always Encrypted (also: Column-based Encryption). See here how to implement it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-always-encrypted-azure-key-vault?tabs=azure-powershell

Answer (score 1):

BTW it is Key Vault not Key Volt, From the docs Definition

> Azure Key Vault is a tool for securely storing and accessing secrets.
>   A secret is anything that you want to tightly control access to, such
>   as API keys, passwords, or certificates.

Is it possible with Azure Key Volts?

**No**

If you want to encrypt data columns of SQL server you need to use [Encryption at Rest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/business-central/dev-itpro/security/transparent-data-encryption)

Comment: Thanks Sajeetharan.

I made change. Its my typo.

Is it possible to use Key Vault in Logic app to encrypt the data.

Comment: yes you can https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-always-encrypted-azure-key-vault?tabs=azure-powershell

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Much helpful.